# Spring Data JPA slice underlying SQL

Tags: java, sql, spring, spring-data-jpa

I was reading this paragraph in the Spring Data JPA official documentation about the difference between `Page` and `Slice` (emphasis mine):

> The first method lets you pass an org.springframework.data.domain.Pageable instance to the query method to dynamically add paging to your statically defined query. A Page knows about the total number of elements and pages available. It does so by the infrastructure triggering a count query to calculate the overall number. **As this might be expensive (depending on the store used), you can instead return a Slice. A Slice only knows about whether a next Slice is available, which might be sufficient when walking through a larger result set.**

I get it how a `Page` can get the total elements by executing an additional count query with the same where clause, but how does a `Slice` gets to know whether other elements are available or not with a single query? What is the SQL executed?

Comment: I'd like to also ask if it is a slice of a sort, will that actually be slower than a pageable? i.e. PageRequest.of(0, 10, Direction.DESC, "createdTimestamp")

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> How does a Slice gets to know whether other elements are available or not with a single query?

Spring Data JPA selects one element more than actually needed to fill the `Slice` if that additional element is present, there is another `Slice` available. If not this is the last `Slice`.

[See the code](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-jpa/blob/f876f7cca5965a7d606fd438d54e657608a4db8f/src/main/java/org/springframework/data/jpa/repository/query/JpaQueryExecution.java#L170).

Comment: just a doubt on this.. As there is no offset needed so then do we have to pass the pagesize incrementally like if the the page size is 10, then on every infinite scroll trigger I have to pass page size as 10,20,30,40 and so on ?

Comment: @VishalNair what do you mean by "there is no offset needed"? You still have to provide a `Pageable` which has an offset, which might be `null`. Page size has to be whatever page size you want. I think this should be asked as a proper question with more details about what problem you are trying to solve.